# firebase authentication for web logs in user even with wrong password

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase by google to develop a web app. I have made a sign up form through which i create new users.

```
document.querySelector('#sign-in-  button').addEventListener('click',function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var form = document.querySelector('#sign-in-form');
  var email = form.email.value;
  var password = form.email.value;
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(err) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = err.code;
  var errorMessage = err.message;

});
```

This works fine and the new user is showing in my console. But when after signing out i sign in again with a sign-in form with a wrong password using same email.

```
document.querySelector('#sign-in-

button').addEventListener('click',function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var form = document.querySelector('#sign-in-form');
  var email = form.email.value;
  var password = form.email.value;
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(err) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = err.code;
  var errorMessage = err.message;
  if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
    alert('Wrong password.');
  } else {
    alert(errorMessage);
  }
  });
});
```

it does not show error. i even tried

```
firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

but it does not show null.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are incorrectly getting the password:

```
var password = form.email.value;
```

It should be:

```
var password = form.password.value;
```